# Format time in java

Tags: java, time, format

I have a text box for time that takes input as String and I have to convert it to a format that has a space between the number and AM or PM.

Eg: 5:00PM has to be converted into 5:00 PM

Comment: Have you tried _anything_? This isn't a code writing service. Post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using in Date/Time formatting features.

Note that it will throw parse errors if the input is not in the correct format.

If the AM/PM segment is guaranteed to be upper case the toUpperCase() call can be removed.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q42913242;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    static final DateTimeFormatter FROM_PATTERN = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma");

    static final DateTimeFormatter TO_PATTERN = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(convert("5:00pm"));

        System.out.println(convert("12:00AM"));
    }

    public static String convert(String input) {
        final LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(input.toUpperCase(), FROM_PATTERN);
        return localTime.format(TO_PATTERN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring for it, eg.:

```
    String time = "5:00PM";
    String newTime = time.substring(0,time.length()-2) + " " + time.substring(time.length()-2);
```